# cloud run and keep alive header

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I think chrome to cloud run is doing http/2 from what I am reading and looking at developer tools, it shows things as http/2 headers(at least I don't think chrome displays it in http/2 header format if it is http1, but I can't tell as I would think this website is http1 but I see http/2 request headers in chrome's dev tools -> https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Performance/microscape/).

Anyways, I am wondering for cloud run if I loop and keep calling a json endpoint to delivery pieces of a file to cloud storage, will it stay connected to the same instance the entire time such that my upload will work with the ByteReader in the server.  In this way, I can load large files as long as it loads within the cloud run timeout window.

Does anyone know if this will work or will cloud run see each json request form chrome hit the firewall and the firewall might round robin it among cloud run instances?

Answer (score 1):

> Anyways, I am wondering for cloud run if I loop and keep calling a
> JSON endpoint to deliver pieces of a file to cloud storage, will it
> stay connected to the same instance the entire time ...

The answer sometimes it will and sometimes it will not. Do not design something that depends on that answer.

What you are looking for is often termed **sticky sessions** or **session affinity**.

Google Cloud Run is designed as a **stateless** service.

Google Cloud Run automatically scales container instances and load balances **every** request. Cloud Run does not offer any session stickiness between requests.

[Google Cloud Run: About sticky sessions (session affinity)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets#sticky-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run offer [bidirectional streaming and websocket support](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-websockets-http-2-and-grpc-bidirectional-streams). The timeout is still limited to 1 hour, but it's a suitable connection to stream your large file into the same instance (don't crash the instance memory size, remember that even the file that you store take space in memory, because it's a stateless service)

A bad solution is to set a max instance to 1. It's a bad solution, because it's not scalable and, even if most of the time, you will have only one instance, sometime Cloud Run service can provision 2 or more instances and only guaranty you that only one is used at the same time.